# where can I find the Specifications of a Blade Server?

Tags: blade-chassis

how can I find the CPU and speed of a UCS B230 Blade server? The chassis that I have do not power on and I was wondering if there is another way to find the specifications of these servers (ie. serial number etc.?  My last resort is to take the heat sink off and check and then put it back on (yes, I know I need to clean and prep before I reset the heat sink unit).

Answer (score 1):

You can just query the OS for this information. As an example, on Linux `cat /proc/cpuinfo` will show you detailed information about the CPU of the system, including its speed.

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 45
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2640 0 @ 2.50GHz
...
```

Noticing the "doesn't power on part" just now ...

In this case your best resort is to look into the invoice or check if the vendor offers a hardware database you can query by serial number.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you have a login, you can, on Cisco's website, inspect the details of the machine, you will need a cisco account and provide the serial number of course.

You can also find the invoice, as Sven suggested.

If you do not have access to Cisco and have no invoice, you will indeed have to remove the heatsinks, clean off any paste ... make sure you clean it afterwards and apply a nice fresh layer of paste if you want to use the chassis again.

You might also want to try and figure out why they do not power on ...

Comment: The units are UCS 5108, and from what it looks like, they need another unit to turn the DC power into AC power. plus the units don't have a power button on them so that is why we think this is the problem with them powering on.